# Обработка сигналов в дочернем процессе

Tags: c, shell, signal

Помогите разобраться.
Пишу оболочку с job control. Основной процесс должен игнорировать все сигналы кроме SIGCHLD (на этот должен быть обработчик с waitpid).
А после вызова fork() в дочернем процессе все сигналы должны сбрасываться в SIG_DFL.

Не могу понять как правильно использовать sigaction().

Вначале основного процесса задаю обработчик

```
void    signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGCHLD)
        check_and_wait();
    return ;
}

void    set_signals() {

        struct sigaction act;

        ft_memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
        act.sa_handler = signal_handler;

        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGINT);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGQUIT);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGTSTP);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGTERM);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGTTIN);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGTTOU);
        sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGCHLD);
        sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGTTIN, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGTTOU, &act, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);
}
```

А что делать дочернему процессу? Создавать новую struct sigaction и указать sa_handler = SIG_DFL?

Comment: `Основной процесс должен игнорировать все сигналы кроме SIGCHLD` — для этого есть [`sigprocmask(2)`](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=sigprocmask&category=2), устанавливать все подряд сигналы в игнорируемые довольно странное занятие...

Comment: ну это в гнушном мануале сказано игнорировать: _When a shell enables job control, it should set itself to ignore all the job control stop signals so that it doesn’t accidentally stop itself. You can do this by setting the action for all the stop signals to SIG_IGN._

Comment: мм... не заметил, что ты свою оболочку пишешь... в таком случае соглашусь, игнорировать сигналы связанные с терминалом (а не вообще все) вполне разумно... ЗЫ: стоит указывать цитируемые источники по возможности...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы установить собственный обработчик сигнала типовая последовательность действий выглядит так:

```
struct sigaction act;
// очистка памяти выделенной под структуру
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
// задание обработчика
act.sa_handler = signal_handler;

// задание маски дабы избежеть вложенного вызова сигнала
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGCHLD); 

// собственно установка обработчика
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);
```

По сути от простой установки обработчика сигнала с помощью `signal(SIGCHLD, signal_handler)` это отличается только тем, что:

- это более переносимый способ (у `signal()` с этим есть проблемы, см. [`man 2 signal`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=signal&category=2&russian=0))
- задаётся маска, защищающая от вызова вложенных обработчиков, что обычно не критично, но в большинстве случаев — хорошая идея.

При этом `struct sigaction` — это просто способ передать данные в одноимённый системный вызов, никакого самостоятельного сакрального значения эта структура не имеет и поддерживать её время жизни сколь-либо продолжительно также не обязательно. Но при этом одну структуру можно использовать для установки сразу нескольких обработчиков.

Для игнорирования сигналов стоит передавать вместо обработчика сигнала `SIG_IGN`, задавать маску в таком случае бессмысленно.

```
struct sigaction act{.sa_handler = SIG_IGN};
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
// ...
```

При этом использование `sigaction()` **в данном случае** не даёт никаких преимуществ перед старым добрым `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)`.

Восстановить обработчики по умолчанию можно аналогично, передав `SIG_DFL`:

```
struct sigaction act{.sa_handler = SIG_DFL};
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
```

---

> Пишу оболочку с job control. Основной процесс должен игнорировать все сигналы кроме SIGCHLD (на этот должен быть обработчик с waitpid). А после вызова fork() в дочернем процессе все сигналы должны сбрасываться в SIG_DFL.

На всякий случай, это имеет смысл только при запуске *подоболочки* (*subshell*, `(command)` в синтаксисе `sh`/`bash`) или встроенных команд в отдельных процессах. При простом запуске сторонних программ сигналы восстановит сам `exec()`, а при обработке чего-либо из этого в основном процессе надо самостоятельно обрабатывать сигналы, а не просто игнорировать.

> ```
> sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
> sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGINT);
> sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGQUIT);
> // ...
> ```

Добавлять в маску для конкретного обработчика всё подряд — ИМХО плохая практика...

> А что делать дочернему процессу? Создавать новую struct sigaction и указать sa_handler = SIG_DFL?

Если кратко, — да, с учётом всего вышеописанного.

---

Помимо описанного, `sigaction()` по сравнению с `signal()` имеет другие дополнительные возможности, которые хотя иногда и крайне важны, в большинстве случаев не используются, см. [`man 2 sigaction`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sigaction&category=2&russian=0) за подробностями.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Многое прояснилось